# Will secondary index create another copy of data in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, secondary-indexes

I have been through [this](https://pantheon.io/blog/cassandra-scale-problem-secondary-indexes) document but here it doesn't say if the data is made a copy of because of secondary index or its just having links to other data ?

Comment: 2is take up space but they're not a full copy of the data like MVs are.

Answer (score 0):

Secondary indexes create a copy of the index table (just index data, not the whole table of data) on each node.  Datastax has a very good write up on how secondary indexes work and when/when not to use them.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSecondaryIndex.html